# Stubs for local Django unittests with Google App Engine

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, google-app-engine

I'd like to run local Django unit tests for a Google App Engine project. GAE recently received some [`python unit testing utilities`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting.html) that allow one to create stubs for e.g. memcache, the datastore, the task queue, etc.

I'd like to be able to use Django's unit testing framework. My first thought is to overload [`DjangoTestSuiteRunner`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing) to do the following for each test case:

```
#     setUp
self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()
# Then activate the testbed, which prepares the service stubs for use.
self.testbed.activate()
# Next, declare which service stubs you want to use.
self.testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub()
self.testbed.init_memcache_stub()

# ... after tests:
#
#     Teardown
self.testbed.deactivate()
```

I'd like to know if anyone else has tried to run Django's testing framework with the new unittests that can be run from the command line for GAE, and if so what pitfalls they've encountered. For example, are there any issues with calling Django's `django.test.utils.setup_test_environment` and `teardown_test_environment`? What other issues might come up?

Incidentally, I'm not using any Django-GAE helpers such as [google-app-engine-django](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-django/).

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to mention: standard django unit testing worked very nice for me with [django-nonrel](http://allbuttonspressed.com) and [GAE Test Bed](https://github.com/jgeewax/gaetestbed), including task-queues, memcache, etc. I think it is the same python unit testing code that you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, Oleksiy. Incidentally, I think the code in question that may cause issues would be here (specifically database issues): https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/test/testcases.py

Comment: It looks like [GAE Test Bed](https://github.com/jgeewax/gaetestbed) is becoming a part of the official Python App Engine SDK. It is the same GAE local testing utils that you mentioned. All I had to do is to use `TaskQueueTestCase` in my `test.py` as the base class, and it did all the `setUp` magic for me.